# Optimize a query with two range conditions

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, subquery, query-performance

I have a structure similar to this one:

```
CREATE TABLE `author` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE `book` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `author_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `org` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `country` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `publish_date` date NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `author_id` (`author_id`),
  KEY `publish_date` (`publish_date`),
  KEY `i0` (`country`, `org`, `author_id`, `price`, `publish_date`),
  KEY `i1` (`country`, `org`, `author_id`, `publish_date`, `price`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6349e2/4)

So I'm trying to execute a query with two range conditions

```
SELECT
  id as author_id,
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `book`.`id`)+1 
   FROM `book` 
   WHERE 
      `book`.`org` = 1
      AND `book`.`country` = 'USA' 
      AND `book`.`publish_date` BETWEEN '2010-04-30' AND '2011-04-30'
      AND `book`.`author_id` = `author`.`id`
      AND `book`.`price` < 50
  ) AS `books_under_fifty`
FROM `author` 
ORDER BY books_under_fifty desc;
```

but the optimizer uses only part of my index: `const,const,db_9_6349e2.author.id` from `i0`

is there a way to optimize it?

Answer (score 4):

Well, let's think out of the box.  It seems that there are two sets of results -- the authors with some such books, and those without.  The first case is more efficiently done via:

```
SELECT  author_id,
        COUNT(*)+1 AS books_under_fifty
    FROM  `book`
    WHERE  `org` = 1
      AND  `country` = 'USA'
      AND  publish_date >= '2010-05-01'
      AND  publish_date <  '2010-05-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
      AND  `price` < 50
```

That would probably be best served by

```
INDEX(country, org, publish_date, price, author_id)
```

If you are happy with the performance of that, then you can think out of the box in finding "the rest of the authors".

Back to the 2-ranges problem.  That can sometimes be solved by Partitioning.  Not knowing the distribution of the data (is one year a small subset of the total? or what about price?), I can't say which would be better:

```
PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(publish_date))
```

Partitioning by price is out, since `DECIMAL` can't be used.  Storing `price` as number of cents and using `PARTITION BY RANGE(cents)` would work, but clumsily.

Then make 20-50 partitions of the partition key.  This would give you "partition pruning" for one 'range', but then the index needs to be tweaked for the other.  Assuming you partition by `publish_date`:

```
INDEX(country, org, price)
PRIMARY KEY(id, publish_date)
```

Meanwhile, ...

Don't use utf8 if you are using standard country_codes; use ascii, at least for that column.

What is `org` does it distinguish the book?  Or are there some missing columns?  Is there no other "unique" column(s)?

Another variant that might be better:

```
 PRIMARY KEY(country, org, price,  -- for clustering
             publish_date,   -- because partitioning requires it
             id)           -- to assure uniqueness
 INDEX(id)
```

This variant assumes you have no 'natural' PK.  And it will be more efficient because it clusters the desired rows together.  I did not include `author_id` in the PK since it is readily available in the row.

**add index**

`ADD INDEX ac(author_id, country)` tricked it into using `i0`.  Go figure.  Note:  I left `(author_id)` intact and first in the list of indexes; so it is not just the order of the indexes.

I'm using Percona's 5.6.22-71.0-log .

Note that there are only 4 different `country` values, evenly distributed.  But there are many different `author_id`, making it *by itself* more "selective".

Comment: Thank you for you answer @Rick James,  partitioning looks like a big topic, and I know nothing about it, you just gave me a subject to read, until I understand you answer. About the distribution: rows are evenly distributed across years, ~1 million rows gets into a year range, `org` is like `organization` but the rows are not evenly distributed, more like 60%/15%/15% for the top 3 (in this case we always filter against the top1). Country can be considered as a field which distribute the rows into 20+ groups, there the top one get 5% of the records.

Comment: Is there an ISBN column?  Or something else that uniquely identifies the book?

Comment: And finally price: rows are normally distributed across price, but only in the context of single org+country, i.e. there is no relation between prices outside org+country. e.g. prices between 1-USA are normally distributed in the range of 20-40, but prices between 2-USA could be normally distributed in the range of 40-80, etc.

Comment: Oh, so this is a table of `book_prices`, not `books`.  There is another table of books?

Comment: I think a combination of all fields (org, country, author, date, price) would uniquely identify a row. And no, there is no `books`, but to be honest in our real world data, its not about books at all I renamed the models + fields to something more generic (author/book), which I think would be still relevant in term of parent-child relation, but I guess I may be wrong.

Comment: Sorry, but the renaming is keeping me from getting a handle on what is going on.

Comment: Yes, sure, I will update the question with relevant model/field data and give more info about how its distributed, but wont be able to do it right now. Tomorrow maybe, I will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your subquery to a `LEFT JOIN`, and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
    author.id as author_id, (count(distinct book.id) + 1) AS books_under_fifty
FROM
    author
    LEFT JOIN book ON
          book.author_id = author.id
      AND book.org = 1
      AND book.country = 'USA' 
      AND book.publish_date BETWEEN '2010-04-30' and '2011-04-30'
      AND book.price < 50
GROUP BY
    author.id
ORDER BY 
     books_under_fifty desc, author_id;
```

... but it really doesn't make any difference with regard to execution plan.

You can check everything at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=7061b93510f66986a46f0f6bc98cb2b1)*

So, I'm afraid the answer is ***most probably, you cannot optimize any further***. I'd recommend, in any case, to test with real data, not with the simulation I used.

NOTES:

1. I've added a second ORDER BY expression, to make sure the order is fully deterministic.
2. Checked with MariaDB, instead of MariaDB first. MySQL uses two different plans, but it even makes a poorer choice (Check at http://rextester.com/JDHP57216)

You can also check a variation of the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    author.id as author_id, coalesce(ccc, 1) AS books_under_fifty
FROM
    author
    LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        author_id, count(distinct book.id) + 1 AS ccc
    FROM
        book 
    WHERE
            book.org = 1
        AND book.country = 'USA' 
        AND book.publish_date BETWEEN '2010-04-30' and '2011-04-30'
        AND book.price < 50
     GROUP BY
          author_id
     ) AS q0
     ON q0.author_id = author.id
ORDER BY 
     books_under_fifty desc, author_id;
```

But, again, it doesn't seem MariaDB gets any advantage.

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=7c5417d394fb417245bfe22547985dfe)*

---

Another Open Source Database (**PostgreSQL 9.6**) can handle things in a far more sophisticated way and can give you execution plans much nicer... (and most probably, faster, although MariaDB didn't get any timings).

PostgreSQL can make the `LEFT JOIN` work faster (in most of the cases, although that depends on the randomness of each execution).

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=030292908a4cb56adaa2e978279c33c6)*

Comment: Thank you for your answer @joanolo, actually the order does not matter (I added it just for representation in the SQL Fiddle), In my real word query I get the exact same query plan (using the index only partially). Moving to PostgreSQL for now would be impossible, but ye I keep reading good staff about it, so maybe one day in the future..). Using a Left join with group by will be hard too, because of the ORM which we use to build this one. This is actually only a part from a bigger query, but since this the main issue of the slowness I posted only this part.

Comment: ORM don't always make your life easier... Does it have some kind of *SQL pass-through*? [Some do](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/)

Comment: yes there is, actually this is the ORM which we use ;) But as you mention *it really doesn't make any difference with regard to execution plan*, however i will give it a try tomorrow. The child table in our real data is a few million records big and the initial execution of this query may took up to 20-30 seconds and cause gateway timeouts for some users. After that, its starts to get faster (300-400ms).

Comment: I'd say "in case of doubt, test all possibilities"... There's no clear winner beforehand in this case. I guess it starts to get faster when you have most of your data cached.